# java pass subclass value to superclass

Tags: java, inheritance, junit, subclass, superclass

Working on Junit testing, running into a problem.

I have a vehicle superclass, and motorcycle and car subclasses. I need to use the methods in the superclass to retrieve information in the subclass (string ID, int arrival)

```
public class MotorCycle extends Vehicle {

public String bikeID;
public int arrivalTimeA;

public MotorCycle(String vehID, int arrivalTime) throws VehicleException {

    super(bikeID, arrivalTimeA);

    bikeID = vehID;
    arrivalTimeA = arrivalTime;
```

Which is the subclass that I am working with, and I want to use the methods from the superclass vehicle to retrieve the information from motorcycle

```
public Vehicle(String vehID,int arrivalTime) throws VehicleException  {

    vehicleID = vehID;
    arrivalTimeA = arrivalTime;

    if (arrivalTime <=0){
        throw new VehicleException("Vehicle");
    }


    public String getVehID() {

    return vehicleID;
}
```

Tried using super(vehID, arrivalTime) in the subclass, but I have to make the variables static which is no good for this program.

Whenever I add super(vehID, arrivalTime), I keep getting errors saying "Make variables static", if I don't it just doesn't run properly and fails.

What I have for my test is:

```
    @Test
public void testGetVehID() throws VehicleException {
    moto = new MotorCycle("b1234", 600);
    veh = moto;
    String id = veh.getVehID();
    assertEquals("b1234", id);// TODO
}
```

veh is just an empty Vehicle class object.

I'm having problems accessing the information. Everytime i run this test or something similar, the value is either 0 for int, or null for Strings

Comment: Why would you need to make variable static for super(vehID, arrivalTime) ?

Comment: is your question is related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14076730/2764279)

Comment: code is fine, what's the problem?

Comment: When I try testing it, the Motorbike isn't passing the values to vehicle

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use constructor to pass information instead of method.
here if you pass 
{super(vehID, arrivalTime);}

to your parent class then it might solve your problem
Please let me you if it works for you or not.

Comment: Would that be in the motorcycle constructor?

Comment: It doesn't work. It says I need to make the variables static, which makes all the other tests fail

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can think of why you'd get that instruction is, if you've been trying to call the superclass's constructor from the subclass's constructor, and it wasn't the first invocation. Calling super() with the constructor's arguments should be easy, as long as there isn't any code before it.