# Initialize superclass variables (needed in constructor) in a subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, subclass, superclass

I'm writing a simple Asteroids-clone game, using `Swing` to display the graphics. I'm kind of following [Derek Banas' tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLE7E8B7F4856C9B19), but decided to expand on my own.

The original idea is that every graphic element in the game (i.e. the Asteroids, the Spaceship and the Bullets) extends the `Polygon` class. Their constructor would look something like this:

```
public class SpaceShip extends Polygon {

    //x and y coordinates
    public static int[] polyXArray = {...};
    public static int[] polyYArray = {...};

    //other class variables
    {...}

    public SpaceShip() {

        super(polyXArray, polyYArray, polyXArray.length);
    }
}
```

And it will be similar for the other graphic elements.

EDIT: The key element here is that the two arrays don't store the actual coordinates of the objects, but their position relative to their centre, whose coordinates are `double`-type class-variable. Thus, the arrays describe just the *shape* of the object, while the subclass `move()` method will affect the centre's coordinates. The class responsible for the actual drawing will call the `move()` method and then apply an affine transform to move and rotate the shape (according to a properly defined angle parameter). I'm doing this to avoid precision problems related to dealing with `double` arithmetic.

Now, since the elements share a lot of "equal" variables (their centre coordinates, which I need in order to translate them with an affine transform, their speed components etc...) and methods (getters and setters, `move()` methods, etc...) I thought about making them be the extension of an abstract class - say, `GameShape` - which holds all these common methods and variables. `GameShape` would now be the one extending `Polygon` directly:

```
public abstract class GameShape extends Polygon {

        //x and y coordinates, still unassigned
        public static int[] polyXArray, polyYArray;

        //other class variables
        {...}

        public GameShape() {

            super(polyXArray, polyYArray, polyXArray.length);
        }
}
```

Then, I'd want to assign the desired value to `polyXArray` and `polyYArray` when I define the different subclasses in order to draw the different shapes I need, but I haven't been able to find a way to do it.

I do want those variable to be static because they are specific properties of the single classes, and I wouldn't want to pass them as a parameter every time I instantiate a new object.

My situation is very similar to the one described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076730/java-initializing-superclass-variables-in-subclasses), but the proposed solution doesn't seem to work, since I need those very variables in the constructor. Is there a way to get over - or around - this problem? Regardless of the procedure, my main aim is to have a superclass common to all the graphic elements, in order to avoid tens of lines of copy-pasted code.

Comment: Are you saying that you want `polyXArray` and `polyYArray` to be static?

Comment: Yes, they would hold the coordinates of the points of my figures, so I thought that it would be a nice idea to have them associated with the specific figured they refer to.

I see that declaring them as static in the superclass might be a bit of a problem and a contradiction, but I don't know how to get around that.

Comment: I do not think that is a wise design decision. You *don't* want all your instances to have the same points. You want them all to be independent of each other. `polyXArray` and `polyYArray` should be instance variables

Comment: You do understand, do you not, that passing an array reference as an argument is no more expensive than passing any other reference, and probably no more expensive than passing a primitive value?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I do understand it. But I wanted to avoid it because I don't think it looks good. Maybe this is naive, but I like more the idea that the points of my shapes are intrinsic to those shapes, that they are "aware" of them (pardon the non-technical jargon). I find it strange to have to pass those values to their constructor every time, since they will always look the same.

Comment: @Michael do you intend instance variables of the subclasses?

Comment: @KaMai They have to be instance variables because different shapes have different coordinates. Why do you want these arrays in the subclasses anyway? They are already in `Polygon`.

Comment: What does `Polygon` look like? Why do you have to have `super(polyXArray, polyYArray, polyXArray.length);`?

Comment: @KaMai, you don't necessarily need to pass the arrays to the constructors of the concrete game object classes, but I still don't understand why you don't want to pass them to their superclass's constructor.  The superclass *doesn't* know what they are.  Nevertheless, my answer describes a means by which you can avoid that.

Comment: @PaulBoddington I want them because they are specific characteristics of the subclass and they describe what the object will look like. They will remain the same throughout the program, so I thought it would have been a reasonable idea to make them specific to the class. Is this a bad idea / bad practice? This is new to me, so I'm trying to get a proper grasp of it.

Comment: @KaMai Wait, are the coordinates the same for all instances of the class?

Comment: @KaMai I think I'm beginning to understand. You have the same basic coordinates for all instances of a subclass. The difference between different instances is that the same coordinates are transformed differently. Is that right?

Comment: @PaulBoddington Yes, I realise I've worded that very badly in my question, and the examples I provided don't represent the situation properly. The idea is that the coordinates are relative to the centre of my object. Said centre has `double` valued coordinates, which are changed via the subclass `move()` method. I'll then use an affine transform (in the class which handles the actual drawing) to translate and - maybe - rotate the coordinates according to the centre and an additional angle parameter. I'm doing this to avoid precision problems dealing with `double` values.

Comment: @KaMai That is the smart thing to do. If you keep applying a bunch of rotations and enlargements etc to a square, it may stop being a square after a while due to floating point errors, but if you do it this way it will **always** be a square. Very clever. The downside is that it means all of the answers  (including mine) are completely wrong. You could make an enum where each constant holds a reference to 2 `double[]` arrays. Then each instance would need to hold an enum constant and various doubles to indicate the transformations. Arrays should not be passed to the constructor.

Comment: @PaulBoddington I should give credit where it's due, this procedure is explained in the tutorial I'm following, I haven't come up with that. My own idea has been to use the superclass to handle all the similarities, but it hasn't proven itself very fruitful thus far.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

EDIT:

As VGR stated in the comments, this will not compile. So, we will have to change the implementation a little, namely, we will use the HAVE relationship instead of IS relationship :-)

First of all, do not make the poly array fields static. If you do, they will be the same for all of the subclasses as well, so what is the point?

Secondly, use a **template method** design pattern here. Your class will look something like this:

```
public abstract class GameShape {

        //x and y coordinates, still unassigned
        public int[] polyXArray, polyYArray;

        private Polygon polygon;

        //other class variables
        {...}

        public GameShape() {
            instantiatePolyArrays();
            this.polygon = new Polygon(polyXArray, polyYArray, polyXArray.length);
        }

        protected abstract void instantiatePolyArrays();

        public final Polygon getPolygon(){
            return this.polygon;
        }
}
```

Every extending class will have to override this method and you can instantiate the arrays for each of the classes in each of the method overrides.

Also, a word about the IS-HAVE relationship problem - what you presented in your example is a IS relationship, in which the `GameShape` object IS a `Polygon`, hence the need to call the super constructor and the problem with that. In my solution this is replaces by a HAVE relationship, in which the `GameShape` object HAS a `Polygon` object inside, accessed with a getPolygon() method. This allows you to have lots of additional flexibility :-)

Comment: That won't compile.  A call to `super(…)` must be the first statement in a constructor.

Comment: True that, corrected my answer with a little relationship swap.

Comment: This works very well and really fits my aim: my objects do have a shape, but many other attributes as well, so a HAVE relationship works best for me.

Answer (score 2):

You have pairs of arrays that describe the shapes of specific kinds of game objects.  If different game objects can have different shapes, then they cannot all share a single pair of arrays, as would be the case if they were static properties of a common superclass of all the game object classes.  Different objects of the same kind can share the same pair of arrays (supposing that those don't need to be *modified* on a per-object basis), which could correspond to those arrays being static fields of the concrete game object classes.  In that case, however, if you want a superclass of those classes to be able to access the correct shape data for a given game object, then it has to be told what those shape data are.

There are two main ways you could do that:

1. You could pass the appropriate shape arrays to the superclass's constructor.  You say you don't want to do this, but I don't understand why.
2. You could define accessor methods on the superclass that the subclasses are supposed to override to provide the correct shape data (this is called the Template Method pattern).

Answer (score 1):

The array fields cannot be `static` because different shapes have different coordinates. Also you don't need these arrays in the specific subclasses because they are already in `Polygon` or `GameShape`.

Here is more-or-less how I would write `GameShape` (although I agree with @Michael that you don't need to pass both `polyXArray` and `polyXArray.length` to the constructor).

```
public abstract class GameShape extends Polygon {

    // I got rid of the array fields as I think they are in Polygon anyway.

    //other class variables
    {...}

    // I added arguments to your constructor.
    public GameShape(int[] polyXArray, int[] polyYArray) {

        super(polyXArray, polyYArray, polyXArray.length);
    }
}
```

The trouble is that `super` must be the first line of a constructor, but you can do it using private methods to build the arrays:

```
public final class BoringRectangle extends GameShape {

    public BoringRectangle(int left, int right, int top, int bottom) {
        super(xArray(left, right), yArray(top, bottom));
    }

    private static int[] xArray(int left, int right) {
        return new int[] {left, right, right, left};
    }

    private static int[] yArray(int top, int bottom) {
        return new int[] {bottom, bottom, top, top};
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think `BoringRectangle` compiles :)

Comment: @bayou.io I've made the helper methods static. Thanks for not down-voting!

Comment: I never downvote. It seems absolutely impossible to access `this` before super constructor is invoked; unless the superclass intentionally provides some backdoor, e.g. invoking an abstract method in constructor! another [workaround](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/java-lang-fans/8kaBhp4Uzq4) I found.

Answer (score 1):

The solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076730/java-initializing-superclass-variables-in-subclasses) will work if your classes will NOT extend shape, but provide shapes via accessor + private static field.

```
public abstract class GameObject {
    ...
    public abstract Polygon getShape();
```

This also helps to escape shapes duplication.

Answer (score 1):

If you really do want to initialize things in your constructor, just call the empty `super();` and then loop against abstract `getPolyXArray()` and `getPolyYArray()` to feed `addPoint`.

```
public abstract class GameShape extends Polygon {

    public GameShape() {
        super();

        final int length = getPolyXArray().length;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            addPoint(getPolyXArray()[i], getPolyYArray()[i]);
        }
    }

    public abstract int[] getPolyXArray();
    public abstract int[] getPolyYArray();

    //common stuff...
}


public class Asteroids extends Polygon {
    public int[] getPolyXArray() { return new int[]{1, 2, 3}; }
    public int[] getPolyYArray() { return new int[]{1, 2, 3}; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think that `polyXArray` and `polyYArray` reside in the `Polygon` class; that's where they belong. Therefore it's not a good idea to have duplicate fields. Also, get rid of the ned to call the `super` constructor. I would design the class structure like this:

```
public class SquareShape extends Polygon {
    private int size;

    public SquareShape(int x, int y, int size) {
        this.size = size;
        int[] xpoints = new int[4]{
                x - size / 2,
                x - size / 2,
                x + size / 2,
                x + size / 2
        };
        int[] ypoints = new int[4]{
                y - size / 2,
                y + size / 2,
                y + size / 2,
                y - size / 2
        };
        setXArray(xpoints);
        setYArray(ypoints);
    }
}
```

This way, you can ensure that all `SquareShape` objects do indeed have a square shape, but you can customize things you should be able to customize. Like position and size, which should not be static shared fields. `setXArray` and `setYArray` should be `protected` methods residing in `Polygon`. You don't want the outside world messing with the individual points. You can add public getters, although.

### NOTE

You may want to consider using a single array of a complex `Point` type, rather then two tightly coupled and dependent arrays. I feel like this will greatly simplify a lot of tasks in your project.