# How can I set ancestor instance variables from an anonymous class?

Tags: java, instantiation, anonymous-class

I have a third party library class which I cannot change, and this has a `protected` instance variable which I wont to set to a non-default value on instantiating. This class has no setter nor a constructor that would allow me to set this instance variable.

I tried

```
// The library class I cannot change:
public class LibraryClass {
    protected boolean instanceVar = false;
}

// My code:
public class MyClass {
    LibraryClass myInstance = new LibraryClass() {
        instanceVar = true;
    };
}
```

but got the compiler error "<identifier> expected" on the line `instanceVar = true;`. I also tried to preceed this line by `this.` and `super.`, but got the same error message.

Of course, I can create a non-anonymous descendant class and set the variable in its constructor. But is there a possibility to initialize the ancestor instance variable directly in an anonymous class?

Comment: In the initialisation block.

Comment: One can also just set the value: `myInstance.instanceVar = true;` (assuming it's accessible)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java — Initializing superclass variables in subclasses?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14076759/2838289)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an instance initializer block:

```
LibraryClass myInstance = new LibraryClass() {
    {
        instanceVar = true;
    }
};
```

Note the additional pair of braces.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the initialisation block:

```
public class MyClass {
    LibraryClass myInstance = new LibraryClass() { 
        {
            instanceVar = true;
        }
    };
}
```